# Mysql subquery in where clause that returns comma separated value

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, subquery, inner-join

I'm not really good at subqueries, here's the sample tables that I have.

```
table customers
=====================
id  | name | order_ids
1   | John | 1,2


table orders
=====================
id  | name
1   | apple
2   | orange
```

I'm trying to get the order names using this query, but I'm only getting one result. I'm not sure if this is possible.

```
select o.name 
from orders o 
where o.id IN(
    select c.order_ids 
    from customers c 
    where c.id=1
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your primary effort should go into fixing your design. You should not be storing several integer values in a string column. If each order belongs to a single customer, then the customer id should be stored in the `orders` table. If an order may belong to multiple customers at once, then you need a bridge table, with one row per customer/order tuple.

That said: for you current design, you can use `find_in_set()`:

```
select o.*
from orders o
inner join customers c on find_in_set(o.id, c.order_ids)
where c.id = 1
```

Comment: "You should be storing" or "You should not be storing"?

Comment: I agree that the DB design is "flawed". But it isn't my call to change our DB design for now.

Comment: @user3437905 You may find that the `FIND_IN_SET()` method gives the right result, but it cannot be optimized with indexes. As the number of rows in your table increases (as it always does), it will get slower and slower. You, or whoever else on your project can make the decision, should redesign this in a normalized fashion ASAP.